# Primary Key and autoincrement: it is possible to increment not even the same value for all the tables?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In a database I have two tables to implement. The primary key of each table is AutoIncremented. So the user simply insert values and each row get its primary key.
But if I have two tables, how can I make the respective primary key different each other?
Here an example:

```
Table brothers
    +------------------+---------+------+
    | id               | Name    | Age  |
    +------------------+---------+------+
    | 1                | James   | 30   |
    | 2                | John    | 12   |
    | 3                | Frank   | 19   |
    +------------------+---------+------+

Table sisters
    +------------------+---------+------+
    | Id               | Name    | Age  |
    +------------------+---------+------+
    | 1                | Donna   | 13   |
    | 2                | Joy     | 15   |
    | 3                | Lucy    | 11   |
    +------------------+---------+------+
```

I have two tables and a primary key (id) that increases its value for each table.
My problem is that these two id are similar.
So, how can I keep the increase and change the value of id?
I'd like to have:

```
Table brothers
    +------------------+---------+------+
    | id               | Name    | Age  |
    +------------------+---------+------+
    | BRO01            | James   | 30   |
    | BRO02            | John    | 12   |
    | BRO03            | Frank   | 19   |
    +------------------+---------+------+

Table sisters
    +------------------+---------+------+
    | Id               | Name    | Age  |
    +------------------+---------+------+
    | SIS01            | Donna   | 13   |
    | SIS02            | Joy     | 15   |
    | SIS03            | Lucy    | 11   |
    +------------------+---------+------+
```

I'm woking in phpmyadmin, so if you post me SQL code, it is not very useful...
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with MySQL autoincrement mechanism, which only deals with numbers and not strings like "BRO". You might be able to do this with a trigger of the "before insert" type.

Answer (score 0):

If you want both tables to have the same increasing primary key remove the primary keys from each table and replace them with a foreign key to a third table which has nothing but an increasing primary key.

Comment: Not remove the primary keys. Keep the primary keys but remove the auto-increment attribute and add the FKs.